# How to tap a button remotely in App1 from App2 in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc, streaming

I am developing 2 apps (App1 and App2). In App1, I have a button to record screen.

Now my question is, is there any way to tap or run the screen recording options in App1 remotely when I tap on a button in App2 ?

I have no idea how to implement this. Need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this, but some may be more complicated than others.
I assume you are using something like `flutter_screen_recording` to start the recording on either of the apps.

1. The easiest would be to create a web server locally on both where one sends the record command while the other listens for it and responds to the other to stop. This would be done through a plugin which starts a background process like `workmanager` and using localhost. Starting a server on localhost would look like this:
   `var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8080);`
2. You could use a common database to indicate changes. `Hive` works well. Then check on the other side for changes using a timer.

````
'dart:async';
main() {
  const checkDelay= Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  Timer.periodic(checkDelay, (Timer t) => check());
}```
````

Comment: Fantastic, I can create a server and send commnad to that server. 

Could you please give me a code example that how can I listen in the brackground using workmanager from my other app.

Isn't workmanager can run a background thread after 15 minutes? Should I need to wait 15 minitues to listen from api?

Comment: That is definitely a big problem I wasn't aware of. Try getting the request from the other side without making a background process. If that doesn't work, use hive to access the same record. I am having a strange a error trying to initialize hive.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did it work?